# Need help converting an excel if and sumif formula to my SQL Server code

Tags: sql-server

I have select SQL query that returns data in the columns I've specified (Customer, Product, Mnth, Previous Yr, Current Yr, Variance), which I export to an Excel table.

In Excel, I added a column to the table (Move) with If's and Sumifs formula that return yes or no based on the criteria in the other columns.

I believe that case when is the equivalent of if's in SQL Server but I can't figure out how to do a case when by row.

Basically the IF statement just says by customer, for each corresponding period between last year and this year, what product are they using less of  and what product are they currently using more of meaning they moved from one product to another.

See Excel and SQL code below and screenshot of result in excel.

**Indented Version of Excel formula:**

```
=IF(
    [@Product]="Product 1",
    IF(
        AND(
            [@Variance]<0,
            OR(
                SUMIFS([Variance],[Customer],[@Customer],[mnth],[@mnth],[Product],"Product 2")>0,
                SUMIFS([Variance],[Customer],[@Customer],[mnth],[@mnth],[Product],"Product 3")>0
            )
        ),
        "Yes",
        "No"
    ),
    IF(
        [@Product]="Product 2",
        IF(
            AND(
                [@Variance]<0,
                SUMIFS([Variance],[Customer],[@Customer],[mnth],[@mnth],[Product],"Product 3")>0
            ),
            "Yes",
            "No"
        ),
        IF(
            AND(
                [@Variance]>0,
                OR(
                   SUMIFS([Variance],[Customer],[@Customer],[mnth],[@mnth],[Product],"Product 2")<0,
                   SUMIFS([Variance],[Customer],[@Customer],[mnth],[@mnth],[Product],"Product 1")<0
                )
            ),
            "Yes",
            "No"
        )
    )
)
```

**SQL that produces the first 6 columns of the attached picture:**

```
SELECT
    subqry.Customer, subqry.Product, subqry.Mnth, 
    SUM(subqry.PriorYr) AS Previous Yr, 
    SUM(subqry.CurrentYr) AS Current Yr, 
    SUM(subqry.CurrentYr) - SUM(subqry.PriorYr) AS Variance
FROM
    (SELECT
         Customer, Product, 
         YEAR(TransactionDate) AS Yr, MONTH(TransactionDate) AS Mnth, 
         0 AS PriorYr, 
         SUM(TransactionCharges + OtherCharges) AS CurrentYr
     FROM
         Storedfunction1 ('01-01-19','03-31-19')
     WHERE
         Customer <> 'internal'   --EXCLUDE INTERNAL CUSTOMERS
         AND Product IN ('Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3')
     GROUP BY
         Customer, Product, YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate)

     UNION ALL

     SELECT
         Customer, Product, 
         YEAR(TransactionDate) AS Yr, MONTH(TransactionDate) AS Mnth, 
         SUM(TransationCharges + OtherCharges) AS PriorYr, 
         0 AS CurrentYr
     FROM
         Storedfunction1 ('01-01-18','03-31-18')
     WHERE
         Customer <> 'internal'   --EXCLUDE INTERNAL CUSTOMERS
         AND Product IN ('Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3')
     GROUP BY
         Customer, Product, YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate)
    ) Subqry
GROUP BY
    subqry.Customer, subqry.Product, subqry.Mnth
ORDER BY 
    1, 2, 3
```

I would like to create the 7th column (Move) and do the calculation in SQL rather than in Excel because I want to limit the calculations that happen in Excel. So create the column I create in Excel in SQL and do the Excel ifs in SQL too.

I hope I'm explaining my request and expected results clearly enough but let me know if I need to clarify. Thanks

[image: Excel_Result_Table]

Comment: I'm afraid we can't use your image as data, so this makes it a lot harder. Excel Worksheets and SQL Server Tables are completely different though, so the first thing you actually need to do if not think of a table like a work sheet. Personally I think you would be better off showing us what your sample data looks like (as formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements) and then show us the results you're after. Telling us your Excel expression is probably only a distraction here, as the syntax is very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I see your general logic.  A little clarification though: it's not so much that a person has 'moved from one product to another', which to me implies that they now have an entirely new preference.  Rather, it's more like a person has 'inched away from the current product' in favor of another.  Though beware that really capturing that is best done by taking the variance of the proportion of money spent, not the absolute variance.  That aside, this is how I approached it:

Rather than subqueries, I prefer to work with common table expressions (CTEs) if I can.  In this case, I split the logic into three tiers.

- In the first CTE, which I call 'baseData', I keep data unagregated and do
  the union there.  The actual year doesn't matter, so I converted to a
  descriptive string instead of a number.  Keep in mind that I'm doing
  this for readability and style, not for performance reasons.  So you
  may have to work with it.  Mainly, I advise that you you'd bypass
  your 'storedFunction1' and hit the underlying table directly.  But
  that's your perogative.
- In the second CTE, called 'getVariances', I calculate the variance
  between the previous and current year.  Note that when no condition
  matches a case statement, null is returned.  So the aggregations in
  this area only add up 'cur' and 'prev' years, respectively.
- In the final sql statement, I calculate 'move'.  Look into windowed
  functions for your needs.  Basically, it takes aggregations without
  condensing the dataset, which is what you need here and what I
  believe is equivalent to what you're trying to do with your sumifs.

Here's the code:

```
with

    baseData as (

        select 'prev' as yr, Customer, Product, TransactionDate, TransactionCharges, OtherCharges
        from Storedfunction1 ('01-01-19','03-31-19')

        union all
        select 'cur' as yr, Customer, Product, TransactionDate, TransactionCharges, OtherCharges
        from Storedfunction1 ('01-01-18','03-31-18')

    ),

    getVariances (

        select      Customer, Product, mnth,

                    variance = 
                          sum(case when yr = 'cur' then transactionCharges + otherCharges end)
                        - sum(case when yr = 'prev' then transactionCharges + otherCharges end)

        from        baseData
        cross apply (select mnth = month(transactionDate)) ap
        where       Customer <> 'internal'   
        and         Product in ('Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3')
        group by    Customer, Product, mnth

    )

    select      *,

                move = 
                    case 
                    when variance >= 0 then 'no' 
                    when max(variance) over(partition by customer, mnth) > 0 then 'yes'
                    else 'no'
                    end

    from        getVariances
```

Comment: Great answer and direction you gave @pwilcox I really appreciate it. So I took your code and modified it and now have a new problem. I thought I should post it here since it is still related to this somehow or is it a new question? All comments welcomed.

Comment: Generally you post a new question.  Put in a link to this question from the new though if it would help the user.  Also, create a minimal reproducible working example of the problem you're facing.  I'm not saying you could have simplified your work above.  But to the extent you can in your new problem you'll get more people trying to help you out.  Good luck, and put my name in a comment under your new question if you want me to look at it.  Good luck.

Comment: @pwilcox, I don't think you can reference someone who hasn't interacted on a page, so when the OP here commented to you, it likely didn't notify you. But here's his [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56500561/5790584)

Comment: Didn't know that.  Thanks @EricBrandt.